# Separate while loops within eachother

Tags: php, mysql

I had posted the code before but had asked it differently as I didn't really know what was going on.

I have several while loops fetching data from the database to form a feed of the latest information. Before you ask I will use mysqli but am just using mysql for now so i can get the loops sorted because i feel more comfortable this way.

Each sql query can but not definitely have several rows of data so a while loop is needed. I also must organize all the data into an array at the end so it can all be ordered by timestamp (timestamp not in sql query yet).

The problem I am having is that to organize it all into the array, with the way it is done now, all the closing curly brackets must be after the array so that every bit of data can be put into it. Due to this some variables could be outputted more than once because there can be different numbers of rows in each sql query. The brackets are not arranged like this at the moment by the way.

In the code below the brackets for each of the second lot of while loops are straight after the variables. This means only one row in the table is outputted into the array.

I hope that that explains it. It's the best I could do. How can I arrange the while loops so that ALL data from EACH of the second lot of querys can be outputted into the array?

```
<?php
    //fetch favourited artist(s)
    $fetchartistFavourite = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artistfavourites WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pass';")or die(mysql_error());
    while ($artistFavourite = mysql_fetch_array($fetchartistFavourite)){

        $favouritedArtist = $artistFavourite['artistname'];
        $favouritedArtistUrl = $artistFavourite['artisturl'];

        //fetch favourite track(s)
        $fetchtrackFavourite = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM trackfavourites WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pass'")or die(mysql_error()); 
        while ($trackFavourite = mysql_fetch_array($fetchtrackFavourite)){
            $favouritedTrack = $trackFavourite['artistname'];
            $favouritedTrackUrl = $trackFavourite['artisturl'];

            //Get news from favourited artist(s)
            //Get updates to bio
            $fetchupdatedBio = mysql_query ("SELECT bio FROM members WHERE artistname = '$favouritedArtist'")or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($updatedBio = mysql_fetch_array($fetchupdatedBio)){
                $updatedBio = $updatedBio['bio'];
            }

            //Get any new pictures
            $fetchPic = mysql_query ("SELECT picurl FROM pictures WHERE artistname = '$favouritedArtist'")or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($pic = mysql_fetch_array($fetchPic)){
                $pic = $pic['picurl'];
            }

            //Get any new tracks
            $fetchTracks = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE artistname = '$favouritedArtist'")or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($tracks = mysql_fetch_array($fetchTracks)){
                $trackurl = $tracks['trackurl'];
                $trackname = $tracks['trackname'];
            }

            //Get any new gigs
            $fetchGigs = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM gigs WHERE artistname = '$favouritedArtist'")or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($gigs = mysql_fetch_array($fetchGigs)){
                //arrange gig data into format to be echoed
                $gig = $favouritedArtist.' is playing for the gig ' .$gigs['gigname'].' at ' .$gigs['venue'].' on the '.$gigs['day'].'th of '.$gigs['month'].', '.$gigs['year'];
            }

            //Get any new sessions
            $fetchSessions = mysql_query ("SELECT title FROM sessions WHERE artistname = '$favouritedArtist'")or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($sessions = mysql_fetch_array($fetchSessions)){
                $sessionName = $sessions ['title'];
            }

            //Get new tracks from favourited tracks(s)if the artist has not been favourited
            $fetchnewTrack = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE artistname = '$favouritedTrack' AND artistname !='$favouritedArtist'")or die(mysql_error()); 
            while ($newTrack = mysql_fetch_array($fetchnewTrack)){
                $trackname2 = $newTrack['trackname'];
                $trackurl2 = $newTrack['trackname'];
            }

            //asign all variables into an array
            //echo array

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have no SQL injection protection. That's not something you should "wait until you're comfortable with the loops" to add. If you migrated to PDO now, prepared statements would prevent injection attacks and you could skip this messy deep nesting with `fetchAll()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should have been indented since the beginning.
In order to get help, please at least make yourself helpable.

Now let's see where the problem is.
If I did correctly get your problem, just use temporary arrays for each of your requests.
But, as said, PDO gives you a powerful tool named fetchAll. You should give it a look.

( http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers )

Comment: Code reformatting is better suited for an edit than an answer unless you are posting the answer now

Comment: No problem. Did you post it as an edit? @ reply me because 2 people with 2000+ rep have to approve your edit

Comment: Or I could just approve it, thanks for the edit by the way. I've never used temporary arrays before so I  shall see if it works. That is another great reason why I should learn pdo. I went for mysqli because it was easier to go from MySQL oh well.

Comment: Yes, I actually did. And Jacob, you're right. :) And actually you're using some. They're not really temporary, but since you're using them only inside the loops, I'm calling them that way.

Comment: @Jerska Sorry but i'm having trouble with what temporary arrays are and how to use them. Where exactly am i using them and can you lead me to a place to show how i should be using them?

Comment: Actually, any PHP basics tutorial. You have some big lacks of basics in PHP and MySQL, and you wanna do things too quickly. I recommend you just go step by step. People won't help you on questions you should be able to get your answer alone.